# Rendering of ListView Items in QML - Emulator

Tags: listview, rendering, emulation, qml

Hello I have the following simple QML app:

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import com.nokia.symbian 1.0

Window {
   id: window

   StatusBar {
       id: statusBar
       anchors.top: window.top
   }

   TabBar {
       id: tabBar
       anchors.top: statusBar.bottom

    TabButton {
        id: someButton
        text: "Something"
        tab: somePage
    }
}

TabGroup {
    id: tabGroup
    anchors.top: tabBar.bottom
    anchors.bottom: toolBar.top
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    Page {
        id: somePage
        ListView {
            id: someLView
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: someModel
            delegate:
                    Text {
                        text: name
                        color: "white"
                    }
        }
    }
}

ToolBar {
    id: toolBar
    anchors.bottom: window.bottom
    tools: ToolBarLayout {
        id: toolBarLayout
        ToolButton {
            flat: true
            iconSource: "toolbar-back"
            onClicked: Qt.quit()
        }
    }
}

ListModel {
    id: someModel
    ListElement {
        name: "Element1"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element2"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element3"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element4"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element5"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element6"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element7"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element8"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element9"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element10"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element11"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element12"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element13"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element14"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element15"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element16"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element17"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element18"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element19"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element20"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element21"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element22"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Element23"
    }
}
}
```

But when I try to run this on an Emulator, this is common behavior when moving the list:

1. First line of the list "Element1" is rendered over the TabBar even
   over the StatusBar
2. Following lines of the list "Element2" to xxx are rendered so that
   when they completely render over the TabBar only then they
   dissapear. (for example "Element2" is already not rendered, but "Element3" is rendered because it is not completely over the TabBar

Any ideas of why is this so? 
See the picture:
[image: Rendering of items in ListView Emualtor]

Update:
I added

```
anchors.fill: parent
```

to the Page element but this did not solve the problem

**SOLVED**
clip: true needs to be added to ListView

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add

```
clip: true
```

to the ListView

Answer (score 0):

You anchored the listview inside the page, but not the page itself.  You didn't specify what the page is supposed to do within the TabGroup.  Try adding anchors to the Page element.

Comment: I added the anchors to the Page element like: anchors.fill: parent, but still the same problem